# Slim 3 - updated Flash messages returning two array values

Tags: php, slim, flash-message, slim-3

So I recently decide to convert my Slim2 application to the newer 3rd version, a lot of the application had to changed and such.

Another thing was flash messages were removed from the core framework so I decided to go and add them back in with composer, I've realized that they have also changed too and for some reason I am getting an array with two values rather than one.

```
$container['flash'] = function ($c) {
    return new \Slim\Flash\Messages();
};

$this->app->flash->addMessage('error', 'hello');

$flash = $this->flash->getMessages();
print_r($flash); // returns Array ( [error] => Array ( [0] => hello [1] => hello ) )
```

My template obviously also complains about this too since it's not of the correct type

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in cache\66\664fc695876aa16573ce7a84cfe29c998af42da36e69199f149219a4e821d44a.php on line 80 Array
```

How am I able to use flash messages the same way Slim2 used them? Or should I even use them, is there a better alternative that is able to do the same job?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash/blob/master/src/Messages.php) call to `getMessages()` returns an array. If you want just one message you can use `getMessage()`. For example `getMessage("error")`.

Comment: Sadly I already tried this function and it still gives me the same result some reason. The only difference in the result with these two functions is the getMessage returns "[0] => hello [1] => hello" rather than "[error] => hello [1] => hello".

Comment: Currently using a temporary solution: $flash = $this->flash->getMessage('error')['0']; until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that hit this problem: Slim is returning a nested array and you need to iterate over both.

```
foreach ($messages as $singlemessage) {
    foreach ($singlemessage as $m) {
      print("<li>{$m}</li>");
    }
}
```

This will take each message set and then print each message inside of it individually. The error "Notice: Array to string conversion" is literally telling you that you're trying to print an array as a string and you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$container['flash']` to your `view` eg:`twig`. If you are using TWIG to render views then you add it like so `$view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $container['flash']);`

Then within you view `{% flash.getMessage('error') %}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$container['flash'] = function ($container) {
  return new \Slim\Flash\Messages;
};

$container->flash->addMessage('error', 'hello');

$flash = $container->flash->getMessage('error');

var_dump($flash);
```

`getMessages()` returns all messages and `getMessage($key)` return only message with specific `$key` for this example `error`;

If you want to access flash object within your twig, you can make middleware for it like `FlashMiddleware`

```
class FlashMiddleware extends Middleware
{
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
  {
    $this->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $this->flash);

    return $next($request, $response);
  }
}
```

for basic middleware

```
class Middleware
{
  protected $container;

  public function __construct($container)
  {
    $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function __get($property)
  {
    if (isset($this->cotainer->{$property})) {
      return $this->cotainer->{$property};
    }
    // otherwise error
  }
}
```

Lastly inside your twig, you could do this

```
{% if flash.hasMessage('error') %}
    {{ flash.getMessage('error') | first }}
{% endif %}
```